# Dúvida em predict de modelos

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, natural-language

Acredito que seja uma dúvida simples, porém em todos os cursos que estou fazendo o instrutor ensina a separar dados de treino e teste de um csv ou alguma base. Porém quero fazer os testes com o input do usuário ao invés disso, mas quando tento, diz que precisa ter o mesmo tamanho que os treinos, não há uma forma de testar só um input?

Exemplo:
[image: Meu dataframe]

Estou usando a coluna tratamento_5 com o seguinte código

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False)
vetor_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(resenha["tratamento_5"])
treino, teste, classe_treino, classe_teste = train_test_split(vetor_tfidf,
                                                              resenha["classificacao"],
                                                              random_state = 42)
regressao_logistica.fit(treino, classe_treino)
acuracia_tfidf = regressao_logistica.score(teste, classe_teste)
print(regressao_logistica.predict(teste).tolist())
```

Esse código separa os dados de teste e treino e prediz com os dados de teste.

Porém quero fazer algo com a interação do usuário, ou seja um texto inserido pelo usuário, tentei dessa forma:

```
vetor_tfidf2 = tfidf.fit_transform(["Esse filme foi muito bom, gostei dos movimentos de ação do inicio até o final do filme"])
treino, teste, classe_treino, classe_teste = train_test_split(vetor_tfidf2,
                                                              resenha["classificacao"],
                                                              random_state = 42)
regressao_logistica.fit(treino, classe_treino)
acuracia_tfidf = regressao_logistica.score(teste, classe_teste)
print(regressao_logistica.predict(teste).tolist())

print(vetor_tfidf2.shape)
print(resenha['classificacao'].shape)
```

Porém me retorna o seguinte erro

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [1, 49459]

Isso me parece que é porque os dados de treino e teste tem tamanhos diferentes, mas como posso fazer somente com uma frase e não usando o dataframe como tentei?

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, o erro ocorre em

```
treino, teste, classe_treino, classe_teste = train_test_split(vetor_tfidf2,
                                                              resenha["classificacao"],
                                                              random_state = 42)
```

Isto porque `vetor_tfidf2` possui apenas 1 item, e `resenha["classificacao"]` possui 49459. Para usar o `train_test_split(X, y)`, `X` e `y` devem ter a mesma quantidade de valores. Cada entrada em `X` equivale a uma classificação em `y`. Ex: `X[0]` possui a classificação `y[0]`.

#### Como testar só um input?

Com a primeira parte do seu código:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False)
vetor_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(resenha["tratamento_5"])
treino, teste, classe_treino, classe_teste = train_test_split(vetor_tfidf,
                                                              resenha["classificacao"],
                                                              random_state = 42)
regressao_logistica.fit(treino, classe_treino)
```

Já temos um `tfidf` e um `regressao_logistica` treinados. Ou seja, **não vamos retreiná-los**. Então a linha `vetor_tfidf2 = tfidf.fit_transform(["Frase que quero testar"])` é incoerente. O certo é apenas transformar a frase com o `tfidf` já treinado. Isto é feito com a função [`.transform()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.transform), assim:

```
vetor_tfidf2 = tfidf.transform(["Frase que quero testar"])
```

Como já temos o modelo treinado, separar novas frases que queremos testar em treino e teste e retreinar o modelo não faz sentido algum. **Tudo que precisamos fazer é pegar as frases e usar no modelo**. Por isso a linha que está dando erro, o segundo `train_test_split()`, pode ser descartada completamente.

As linhas seguintes, `regressao_logistica.fit(treino, classe_treino)` e `acuracia_tfidf = regressao_logistica.score(teste, classe_teste)` também devem ser descartadas. Não queremos retreinar o modelo.

Por fim, seu segundo bloco de código (para testar novas frases) deveria ser:

```
# uso o tfidf já treinado para transformar a nova frase
vetor_tfidf2 = tfidf.transform(["Frase que quero testar"])

# aplico a frase transformada como entrada do modelo já treinado
print(regressao_logistica.predict(vetor_tfidf2).tolist())
```

Uma ressalva é que o modelo foi treinado com frases que sofreram um tratamento. Para usar novas frases, é justo aplicar o mesmo tratamento nas novas frases antes de usá-las como entrada do modelo.